# What is wrong with my code? I am trying to authenticate a user login with expressjs and mysql?

Tags: mysql, express

I am trying to figure out what part is wrong? I get this error:

ERROR-----
var pwdCompare = await bcrypt.compare(password, pwdCompare[0].password);
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
ERROR-----

Registering a user is fine. I also hash the password in the user registration... I think i have syntax error or missing code... I just want to figure this part out before I move on to creating a session and a webtoken.
'''
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {

```
var email = req.body.email;
var password = req.body.password;

db.query('SELECT clientID, email, password FROM registration WHERE email = ? AND password = ?', [email, password], async (err, data) => {
    
    

    if (err) {
        throw err;
        
    }
    else if (data[0].password.length == 0) {
        res.locals.messages = req.flash();
        req.flash('info', 'User not found');
        return res.render('login');
    }
    
    
    else {

        let pwd = data[0].password.length;
        
        if (await bcrypt.compare(password,pwd)) {
            res.locals.messages = req.flash();
            req.flash('info', 'Login Successful');
            return res.render('dashboard'); 
        }

        else {
            res.locals.messages = req.flash();
            req.flash('info', 'Login Unsuccessful');
            return res.render('login');
        }
    }
});
```

'''

ok so after reading the first answer i changed the code and now i get this error
ERROR____
var pwdCompare = await bcrypt.compare(password, data[0].length);
^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
ERROR___

3rd revision
so i modified the code again with two parameters in the method and also modified the part you mentioned, but now i am getting this error:

ERROR___
var pwdCompare = await bcrypt.compare(password, data[0].password.length);
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'password')
ERROR___

4th Revision
I modified the code slightly and i still get the same error.
ERROR___
else if (data[0].password.length == 0) {
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'password')
ERROR___

I cant figure it out.. i dont understand why it cant read it..

Comment: `var pwdCompare = await bcrypt.compare(password, pwdCompare[0].password);` defines `pwdCompare` with a reference to itself. This cannot work.

Comment: thank you for answering my question.. I changed the method parameter to data and I got a different error I wrote in the question what the error is ... what does that mean?

Comment: `data` consists of `clientID, email, password`, so you must write `data[0].password.length`.

Comment: thank you for helping... i made some changes and now i get this error is it related to the hashed password saved in MYSQL??

Comment: Your code is not prepared for the case `data.length === 0`.

Comment: ok. so i dont think that its related to that because I modified the code slightly and it is still not able to read the properties. I dont understand what that error means...

Answer (score 0):

`pwdCompare` is undefined at compare method's second parameter.

Comment: thanks for answering. can you look at it my modified code and tell me why i get that error?